# Index MIPS array with an integer loop counter

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

```
global:
int alpha[8] = { 0xb1, 0xe1, 0x91, 0xc1, 0x81, 0xa1, 0xf1, 0xd1 }; 
int beta[8] = { 0x0, 0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x50, 0x60, 0x70 };

main:
int j = 0;
int k = 7;

  loopTop1: //converted while loop to Goto-C
  if ( j == 8) goto loopEnd2;
  alpha[j] = beta[k];
  j++;
  k--;
  goto loopTop1;

  loopEnd2:
return 0;
```

I'm trying to convert the following code snippet to assembly. This is what I have so far:

```
    .data
    .globl alpha
alpha:  .word 0xb1, 0xe1, 0x91, 0xc1, 0x81, 0xa1, 0xf1, 0xd1
    .globl beta
beta:   .word 0x0, 0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x50, 0x60, 0x70


main:

    la  $s6, beta       # x = beta
    li  $s3, 0          # j = 0
    li  $s4, 7          # k = 7
    
loopTop1:
    beq     $s3, 8, loopEnd1

    addi    $s3, $s3, 1     # j++
    sub     $s4, $s4, 1     # k--
    
    j   loopTop1
    
loopEnd1:
\\end
```

I have to do this without using pointer arithmetic. The instructions are: "
The translation of the while loop should include      generation of the address of alpha[j] by adding 4 times j to
the address of alpha[j], and a similar thing for beta[k]." I'm having trouble storing the address of beta[k], storing the value of it into a register, and then storing the value of the register into alpha[j].

Comment: The process it describes for finding the address of `alpha[j]` *is* pointer arithmetic.  I suppose they mean you can do what an optimizing C compiler would do and strength-reduce by turning that shift/add every iteration into just an `add reg, reg, 4` pointer-increment.

Comment: But anyway, what trouble?  What have you tried?  There's no attempt at the part you're asking about.  You could of course ask a C compiler to make an example for you.  https://godbolt.org/ has MIPS GCC.  Also note that "store" generally implies reg -> memory.  You want to *load* from the address `beta + k`, then store that value into memory at `alpha + j`.  (Where those are C expressions equivalent to `&beta[k]` and so on, so I left out the scaling by type-width that you need in asm.)

Comment: @PeterCordes  I deleted my work since it wasn't compiling but yeah I wanted to use lw $s1, (4*k)($s5) but this gives a compilation error. I want to load from beta+4k so how would I go about doing this? I tried storing the value of 4*k in $t0 and then tried lw $s1, $t0($s5) where s5 holds the address of beta

Comment: What addressing modes does MIPS support?  Just one, constant(reg).  So clearly you have to do the pointer math with other instructions.  That wording in your assignment is misleading.